# Printing iPython Notebook preview in color?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Windows Python 2.7.6 and iPython 2.0.0.  When I do a print preview on a notebook, I get a gorgeous color output with syntax highlighting, etc.

As soon as I either do a print preview, or print it, it becomes gray scale and loses the syntax highlighting.  How can I print keeping the color and highlighting?

Answer (score 10):

One workaround is, save the notebook as html. The rendered file will have the css embedded. Open the HTML in a text editor and do a search for

`@media print`

and delete the offending

`!important;color:#000`

save, open the file in a browser and print.

It's not ideal but you don't have to go digging around changing the CSS and recompiling in your site-packages.

Just in case someone is looking for an easier workaround.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but for people who may be searching for this answer, here it is:

IPython on windows would be installed by default at `C:\Python27\site-packages\IPython`.  If you installed Python somewhere else, the beginning of the path will change.  For linux users, it would be installed under `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython`.

Once in the IPython folder, go to `html\static\style`. You should then see a file called `style.min.css`.

Making sure you have administrator priviledges, open `style.min.css` with your favorite text editor. If you don't know what I mean by text editor, just double click. In `style.min.css` find the line that starts with `@media print`.  On that line, near the beginning, you will see `color: #000 !important;` Delete only that part of the line and save the file.

I have IPython 2.3.0, so it may be different in you version, but this is what the line I am talking about looks like before and after the change (only part of line is shown):

```
@media print{*{text-shadow:none !important;color:#000 !important;background:tran...

@media print{*{text-shadow:none !important;background:transparent !important;box...
```

Comment: This works for the plots!  (Is there any way to allow the syntax highlighting to be colored as well?)

Comment: That doesn't work for syntax highlighting? Hmmm, it worked for me. Could you put up a pastebin or gist with your `style.min.css`?

Comment: It looks like the `style.min.css` has moved from the `IPython` to the `notebook` folder. So to
`site-packages/notebook/static/style/style.min.css`